# How to refresh just one side of the page

Tags: refresh

See http://myownmealplanner.com/mealplans/add/5 for the example
If you drag a meal tile to the right side of the page then it should stay there after you click on [Go back to list of meal tiles](/mealplans/add) but of course it doesn't because the entire page gets refreshed. I tried adding an anchor for just the mealplan tiles (like a back to top button) but still the entire page gets refreshed. I can't think of any way to do this with jquery, javascript or php. Any ideas? You're supposed to be able to add tiles from the 500 calorie list and then for example the 300 cal list. Right now I only have 500 calorie tiles but you can see how it's supposed to work. This was made with the cakephp framework but it's principally the same as for a normal website.

If you start with http://myownmealplanner.com/mealplans/add/5 and click on the "100 cal tiles" div you get the ajax message "Request successful
MEAL TILES" because of

```
<div id="clickMe">100 cal tiles</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
  $('#result').load('test');
});
</script>
```

The problem with Cakephp though is that it seems to have only one ajax.ctp file for all of the loads so I can't make 8 separate messages, one for each tile collection. How do I load for example the CTP called test without using the same ajax.ctp file as for the other ones? I need a separate ajax.ctp for every callback.

Comment: Google for Ajax... Other keywords: XHR, XmlHttpRequest, etc.

Comment: I took the advice of Rasmus Lindström at http://www.devppl.com/forum/post71111.html#p71111 and used a GET variable to get different code for each ajax page but now the meal tiles aren't in the view source and thus aren't draggable.

Comment: I was thinking maybe if I loaded an XML file with ajax I might be able to see it in view source but now I keep getting the error "failed to load external entity tiles.xml" Should I keep trying to create draggable divs with xml or am I on the wrong path here anyway?

Comment: I got it to load the XML file but the XML doesn't show up in View Source either so I won't be able to use it.

Comment: Here is the dilemma. If I use Ajax and even Ajax with an external XML source it doesn't show up in the view source so there's nothing to drag. If I use an iframe the draggable divs aren't on the same page as the droppable box. The last possibility would be sessions but how can I make sessions in the jquery drop function? The user would have to push some sort of button to get to the PHP.

Comment: If I write <?php 
   $i = 7;
   $this->requestAction('/mealplans/createsessions/'. $i);
   ?>
in my jquery function it echos back the 7 because requestAction goes to a method in the controller that creates a session with that value. How do I get the jquery index instead of the one I'm using as a placeholder? In jquery I have a definition for i as well but I can't get it to go to the php.

Comment: The solution at http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?270587-How-to-refresh-just-one-side-of-the-page&p=1242625#post1242625 by xelawho shows how I can hide and show my navigation and draggables with javascript. I will probably use his solution but it will take a lot of work and I'm not ready to get started with it yet.

Comment: I tried implementing the jquery toggle function for 300, 400, and 800 meal tiles but there is a problem when you toggle back and forth. If you try clicking on for example the 300 cal tiles and then dragging the tile to the right side you will see that if you click on it again that it will disappear from the right side as well.

Comment: I gave the draggable divs a new class called rightSide when they're dragged to the right side. You can see that the class has changed because the background color turns to pink. Now that it's a new class I can ask it to show instead of toggle like this:

  $("#clickMe3").click(function() {
  $(".rightSide").show();
  $("#showMe3").toggle();
    });

But instead of showing the right side divs, it toggles back to hide just like the left side divs do. At http://myownmealplanner.com/mealplans/add you can click on the 300, 400, 800 tiles to try it out.

Comment: xelawho at http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?270587-How-to-refresh-just-one-side-of-the-page&p=1242743#post1242743 suggested I use $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this)); to keep the divs on the right side and now they don't hide when I toggle. It's pretty much working as desired now.

Comment: I missed your updates until now... Congrats for sorting it out for yourself.